# ServiceWorker's 'fetch': Object that was not a Response was passed to respondWith()

Tags: javascript, async-await, service-worker

Service worker 'fetch' not returning Response object

I'm trying to answer the request with cached content. If the cache doesn't have the required content, I'm fetching from the server, putting the response in the cache and returning it.

```js
self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {
  if (event.request.method != 'GET')
    return;
  event.waitUntil((async () => {
    // some IndexedDB stuff which works fine
  })());
  event.respondWith((async () => { //<----------- this is line 154
    var freshResource = fetch(event.request).then(async function (response) {
      if (!response || response.status !== 200 || response.type !== 'basic') {
        return response;
      }
      if (ENABLE_DYNAMIC_CACHING) {
        var responseToCache = response.clone();
        caches.open(DYNAMIC_CACHE).then(function (cache) {
          cache.put(event.request, responseToCache);
        });
      }
      return response;
    }).catch(function (error) {
      console.err('Error: ' + error.message);
    });
    caches.match(event.request).then(async function (resp) {
      return resp || freshResource;
    }).catch(function (e) {
      return freshResource;
    });
  })());
});
```

When I request a page, it doesn't load, and I get this:

> The FetchEvent for "http://localhost:64228" resulted in a network error response: an object that was not a Response was passed to respondWith(). ... @service-worker.js:154

I wonder if this could have to do with the async stuff...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, inside of an `async` function, it's preferable to use `await` rather than a `.then()` chain to structure your promise-based logic.

Here's a roughly equivalent rewrite. You might need to reorder some of the logic depending on the exact behavior you're after:

```js
event.respondWith((async () => {
  const cachedResponse = await caches.match(event.request);
  if (cachedResponse) {
    return cachedResponse;
  }

  const response = await fetch(event.request);

  if (!response || response.status !== 200 || response.type !== 'basic') {
    return response;
  }

  if (ENABLE_DYNAMIC_CACHING) {
    const responseToCache = response.clone();
    const cache = await caches.open(DYNAMIC_CACHE)
    await cache.put(event.request, response.clone());
  }

  return response;
})());
```

Comment: This really helped me. I somehow got it in my head that I could return the promise and it was failing with the error OP mentioned. Finally got past this!

Comment: For me the issue was thinking I could pass the async function without invoking it... missing that ().